# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(2n)}{\ln(1+n)}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions

> Calculate the limit with L'Hôpital:
>
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(2n)}{\ln(1+n)}$$

I get $2$ as limit but not sure because I tested with calculator and I get some small thing like $0.032\ldots$

$$(\sin(2n))'=2\cos(2n)$$

$$(\ln(1+n))'=\frac{1}{1+n}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\frac{2\cos(2n)}{\frac{1}{1+n}}= \lim_{n\rightarrow 0}2\cos(2n) \cdot(1+n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}2\cos(2n)+2n\cdot \cos(2n)=$$

$$2\cdot \cos(0)+0\cdot \cos(0)=2\cdot1+0\cdot1=2$$

Comment: Did you set your calculator in Radian mode?

Comment: Obviously he did not, since $2\frac{\pi}{180}\approx 0.034$

Comment: Ohhhh thank you it was really in degree mode :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're doing right. When you check the result, please make sure that you calculate the angle using radian mode.